# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: Python

Tags: python

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: выходит после того как я пытаюсь открыть файл.

Тут я запускаю скрипт с меин файла скрин
https://prnt.sc/vm8psi

Дальше этот меин файл запускает скрипт но сначала записывает данные в файл.

```
class Main_Menu:
    def __init__(self, login):
        self.login = login

        with open('scripts/logs/save_log.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(self.login)

        check_lvl_user()
```

После чего в скрипте происходит следущее

```
login = open('logs/save_log.txt', 'r').read()
 
exp_user_from_bd = s.execute("""SELECT exp FROM users_economic WHERE login = (?)"""
                             , (login,)).fetchone()[0]
lvl_user_from_bd = s.execute("""SELECT lvl FROM users_economic WHERE login = (?)"""
                             , (login,)).fetchone()[0]
def check_lvl_user():
    lvl_end   = int(exp_user_from_bd ** (1 / 4))
    if lvl_user_from_bd < lvl_end:
        s.execute("""UPDATE users_economic SET lvl = (?) WHERE login = (?)"""
                  , (lvl_end, login))
        db.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo('Поздравляем', f'Вы достигли {lvl_end}-лвла')
```

Скрипт находитса в данной директории
https://prnt.sc/vm8s9a

А файл в который я записываю данные находитса в
https://prnt.sc/vm8sya

Эту функцию я вызываю в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Записываете в `scripts/logs/save_log.txt`, пытаетесь читать с `logs/save_log.txt`.

Comment: Дело не в этом я уже записываю все в одном файле. Данные записывает а прочитать неможет.

Answer (score 1):

Когда выполняется функция `open(имя-файла)`, и путь к файлу относительный (т.е. начинается не с `/`), то файл ищется не относительно питон файла, из которого идет вызов, а относительно текущей рабочей директории процесса. Посмотреть директорию можно так: `import os; os.getcwd()`.

Файл не находится, потому, что не там ищете. Проверьте перед вызовом `open` что вернет `os.getcwd()` в обоих случаях. Очевидно, что в программе неправильные предположения о текущем рабочем каталоге. Либо используйте полный путь либо по другому синхронизируйте место записи и чтения.