# Не работает open() в Python

Tags: python

Изучаю работу с файлами в питоне и попал в какую-то странную ситуацию: код ниже должен создать текстовый файл some в заранее созданной папке `files`, а после добавить туда текст из `write()`. Проблема в том, что никакой файл вообще не создаётся. Вместо `'a'` на всякий случай попробовал и `'a+'/'w'/'w+'` - ничего не помогло. Путь к файлу записан верно, проверял

```
my_file = open('files/some.txt', 'a')
my_file.write('Some text\n')
my_file.write('End\n')
my_file.close()
```

Comment: скорее всего создаётся, но в другом месте. Не там, где вы ожидаете.

Comment: Добавьте в начало программы `import os; print(os.getcwd())`, это покажет в какой директории запускается программа, в ней и ищите.

Comment: если каталога files нет, то вряд ли оно создаст этот каталог с файлом

Comment: Дело не в коде. У меня он создаёт файл.

Comment: Или пишите полный путь

Comment: а в каком месте находится папка files? совсем необязательно код будет создавать файл в том же самом месте

Comment: @Эникейщик, разве код не создает файл, "стартуя" из каталога, где он находится (=откуда он запускается)? Тогда, если `files` в этом каталоге с файлом *.py и `files` там же, то должно работать, верно?

Comment: @Сергей Нет. Зависит от того, как запускать скрипт. Если запустить, например, в IDLE, то будет в одном месте. А если через командную строку (``python path/to/file.py``), то в другом.

Comment: @Эникейщик,  я имею в виду просто запуск из PyCharm или IDLE. Вряд ли автор доп ключи или окружение как-то задействует. Хотя, если создать каталог у IDLE, а запустить в PyCharm, то да, ошибка и будет:-)

Comment: @Сергей я потому и спросил, где папка files :) А то, может, срипт в проекте пичарма лежит, а папка на рабочем столе :)

Comment: посмотрите еще https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1206986/218971

Comment: @Эникейщик, папка files лежит в одной папке с тем файлом, в котором написан код. (на всякий случай: код пишу в VS Code, но проверил и в PyCharm - то же самое)

Comment: вы `print(os.getcwd())` сделали, как вам советуют? Или полный путь указали?

Comment: @Сергей сделал `print(os.getcwd())` - выдало вот такую ошибку:
 `No such file or directory: 'files/some.txt'`. То есть он искать искал, но не создал в случае ненахождения

Comment: Выполнение данной команды должно выдать что-то вроде: `C:\Users\Jur\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310` Что оно выдало? И какой полный путь вы видите в Проводнике к 'files'? Приведённую вами ошибку выдает никак не команда `print(os.getcwd())`.

Comment: @Сергей, выдаёт вот такое `C:\Users\Юра\Desktop\Программирование\Python`, но только после того, как я закомментировал код.

Если не комментировать, то вот:

`File "c:\Users\Юра\Desktop\Программирование\Python\работа с файлами.py", line 5, in <module>
    my_file = open('C:/Users/Юра/Desktop/Программирование/Python/files/some.txt', 'a') 
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:/Users/Юра/Desktop/Программирование/Python/files/some.txt'`

Comment: Очень странно. Если вы директорию `files` видите своими глазами в директории 'Python', то могу только посоветовать её пересоздать. Вдруг пробел какой в имени. И закомментировать пришлось потому, что команда не первой идёт, полагаю.

Comment: @Сергей, очень странно сейчас получилось: пересоздал еще раз - не помогло, потом решил в ручную еще раз этот код написать. По итогу не углядел в какой конкретно момент, но файл создался и всё заработало. В любом случае большое спасибо!